# Why does iPhone not capture what does the preview layer show?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to create a photo-taking application based on the `AVFoundation` framework. I have a preview layer on the screen and it fills the entire screen as I want.

This is what does the preview layer see: https://ibb.co/47gYQbD

This is what do I get when I capture the photo: https://ibb.co/qkkbf0N

Here is how I create the preview layer object.

```
let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
previewLayer.frame = view.bounds
let previewLayerContainer = UIView()
previewLayerContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height)
view.addSubview(previewLayerContainer)
previewLayer.bounds = previewLayerContainer.bounds
previewLayerContainer.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
```

Photo settings:

```
// AVCapturePhotoSettings object
        let photoSettings: AVCapturePhotoSettings
        
        // Capture HEIF photos when supported
        if self.photoOutput.availablePhotoCodecTypes.contains(.hevc) {
            photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format:
                [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.hevc])
        } else {
            photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        }
        
        //Enable auto-flash and high-resolution photos
        if self.captureDeviceInput.device.isFlashAvailable {
            switch currentFlashStatus {
            case .AUTO:
                photoSettings.flashMode = .auto
            case .ON:
                photoSettings.flashMode = .on
            case .OFF:
                photoSettings.flashMode = .off
            }
        }
        
        photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
        
        //Photo Quality Prioritization
        photoOutput.maxPhotoQualityPrioritization = .quality
        photoSettings.photoQualityPrioritization = .quality
```

Answer (score 1):

The captured photo and your screen have different aspect ratios. When you tell the preview layer to `resizeAspectFill`, it will crop parts of the camera feed to fill the screen. If you want to preview the whole scene instead (at the cost of having black bars in your preview), use `previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect` instead.

Comment: I mostly agree. But the aspect ration difference is between camera and preview view (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) - and not between photo and screen.

Comment: Yes, but I need a full-screen view. Isn't there a way to capture a photo as the same aspect ratio with the preview layer.